# How to check if a c++ typeid(T) call is compile time or runtime determined?

Tags: c++, compilation, runtime, virtual, typeid

C++ keyword `typeid` has a magic: it know when to use compile-time type info and when to use runtime type info:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
struct Interface      { virtual void f() = 0;               };
struct S1 : Interface {         void f() { cout << "S1\n"; }};
struct S3 : S1        {         void f() { cout << "S3\n"; }};
int main() {
    S1 s1;
    cout << typeid(s1).name() << endl;
    S1* ps = new S3;
    cout << typeid(ps).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(*ps).name() << endl;
    delete ps;
    return 0;
}
```

The program prints:

```
struct S1
struct S1 * __ptr64
struct S3
```

My question: does gcc/clang compiler has any compiler macro, or type_traits : that exposes `typeid` magic and tells us whether `typeid(*ps)` is compile-time determined or runtime-determined?

Comment: `typeid` always gives you the runtime type of an object.

Comment: @MilesBudnek afaik it's optimised to run at compile time when the type checked is not polymorphic. Otherwise the check happens at runtime

Comment: Is `std::is_polymorphic_v<T>` (perhaps with `&& !std::is_final_v<T>`) good enough, or do you want to know precisely when the compiler is able to figure out a polymorphic type at compile-time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this out:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto my_typeId(const T& value) {
    auto compileTimeChecked{ true };
    const auto& typeId = typeid(compileTimeChecked = false, value);
    return std::pair<
        decltype(compileTimeChecked),
        decltype(typeId)
    >{ compileTimeChecked, typeId };
}
```

The first argument of the pair has `true` if `typeid` is resolved at compile time. `false` otherwise. The second member is the reference to the resolved type information `const std::type_info &`

---

The trick here is that `typeid` semantic changes depending on the argument it takes. If argument is an instance of a polymorphic class, then `typeid` actually evaluates the expression in runtime, and the side effect of `compileTimeChecked = false` comes into play. Otherwise `typeid` does not evaluate the expression (thus, `compileTimeChecked = false` never happens), but just takes the static type of `value` resolved at compile-time.

**Edit**: as [pointed out by user17732522 in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73379990/how-to-check-if-a-c-typeidt-call-is-compile-time-or-runtime-determined/73380223#comment129592102_73380223),
be advised that when `value` is a polymorphic prvalue, `my_typeId` function actually evaluates it in runtime, unlike the `typeid` which, if passed directly, resolves the type statically. This difference is apparently impossible to get rid of when using functions, just because of how function call work in C++.

Comment: Answer could be improved explaining why it works, but either way very clever.

Comment: Unfortunately `my_typeId` will behave differently than `typeid` if the operand is a prvalue and I don't think that can be fixed. Also it will always evaluate the argument for `value`, contrary to `typeid`. I think this should also be marked `constexpr`.

Comment: @user17732522 thanks for the suggestion. Could you please elaborate the difference for prvalues?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind If the operand is a prvalue of polymorphic type, then your `my_typeId` will claim that it is not compile-time checked, when it really is for `typeid`, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/7Tbee17oq. But you can't differentiate xvalues from prvalues in a function call, so there isn't really much you can do about this. The only way I can think of is to not take the operand directly, but instead a `decltype(auto)` lambda with the typeid operand as `return` operand, which is then called inside the `typeid` in `my_typeId`.